# OpenCV VideoCapture to an image array

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV's VideoCapture function to read in a video, extract the frames and then put them into an array such that I have a 3D image stack. Here's what I have so far:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/jryan/Videos/RMS/20211019_234125-75mm.mkv')
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

image_array = []
for frame in cap:
    if frame_count <= 1000: # only want the first 1000 frames
        continue
    capture = cap.read()
    image_array += capture
```

However I get the error `'cv2.VideoCapture' object is not iterable`. From what I understand there is nothing to iterate through from the video capture - how can I reference the individual frames otherwise?

Comment: use `while True:` `ret, frame = cap.read()`

Comment: or while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()

Comment: you have to use `.append` to add items to a python list.

Comment: @p13rr0m isOpened will always stay true so that's silly. just use `while True:` instead, and check `assert cap.isOpened()` once before the loop

Answer (score 0):

You have just to iterate a `int` variable inside a `for` loop, without using `cap`, that is not iterable. For example:

```
for i in range(1000): #only the first 1000 frames
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       #do your stuff
```